# R - how to replace parts of variable strings within data frame

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
var1 var2
"test" "testing"
"esten" "etsen"
"blest" "estten"
```

Now I want to delete all "t" inside df to get:

```
var1 var2
"es" "esing"
"esen" "esen"
"bles" "esen"
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `gsub`

```
dat <- c("test", "testing", "esten", "etsen", "blest", "estten")

gsub("t", "", dat)
[1] "es"    "esing" "esen"  "esen"  "bles"  "esen"
```

Comment: Works great for me! Just be aware that gsub's first argument is a _regular expression pattern_ and not a plain string.

Answer (score 32):

You can do this with `gsub` and using `sapply` to apply it per variable:

```
df <- data.frame( 
    var1 = c("test","esten","blest"),
    var2 = c("testing","etsen","esttem"))

df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df,gsub,pattern="t",replacement=""))
df2
  var1  var2
1   es esing
2 esen  esen
3 bles  esem
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap a `data.frame()` around the `sapply` to get back to a data.frame, right?