# R: respect quotes around numbers (treat as character) with read.csv()?

Tags: r, csv, formatting

I have a .csv file with account codes in the form of 00xxxxx and I need them to stay that way for use with other programs which use the account codes in this format. I was just working on an R script to reconcile account charges on Friday and *swore* that `as.is = T` was working for me. Now, it doesn't seem to be. Here's some example data:

```
test <- data.frame(col1 = c("apple", "banana", "carrot"),
                   col2 = c(100, 200, 300),
                   col3 = c("00234", "00345", "00456"))
```

My `write.table` strategy:

```
write.table(test, file = "C:/path/test.csv", quote = T,
            sep=",", row.names = F)
```

Remove the old `data.frame` and re-read:

```
rm(test)
test <- read.csv("C:/path/test.csv")
test

    col1 col2 col3
1  apple  100  234
2 banana  200  345
3 carrot  300  456
```

In case it's not clear, it should look like the original `data.frame` we created:

```
test
    col1 col2  col3
1  apple  100 00234
2 banana  200 00345
3 carrot  300 00456
```

I also tried the following, after perusing the available `read.table` options, with the results all the same as above:

```
test <- read.csv("C:/path/test.csv", quote = '"')
test <- read.csv("C:/path/test.csv", as.is = T)
test <- read.csv("C:/path/test.csv", as.is = T, quote = '"')
```

`StringsAsFactors` didn't seem to be relevant in this case (and sounds like `as.is` will do the same thing.

When I open the file in Emacs, `col3` is, indeed, surrounded by quotes, so I'd expect it to be treated like text instead of converted to a number:

[image: emacs screenshot]

Most of the other questions are simply about not treating things like factors, or getting numbers *not* to be recognized as characters, usually the result of an overlooked character string in that column.

I see I can pursue the `colClasses` argument from questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805357/specifying-colclasses-in-the-read-csv), but I'd prefer not to; my "colClasses" are built into the data :) Quoted = character, not quoted = numeric.

Answer (score 4):

After pinging a couple of friends who are R users, they both suggested using `colClasses`. I was relieved to find that I didn't need to specify each class, since my data is ~25 columns. SO confirmed this (once I knew what I was looking for) [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805357/specifying-colclasses-in-the-read-csv).

```
test <- read.csv("C:/path/test.csv", colClasses = c(col3 = "character"))
test

    col1 col2  col3
1  apple  100 00234
2 banana  200 00345
3 carrot  300 00456
```

As it currently stands, the question is a duplicate of the other with respect to the solution. The difference is that I was looking for ways *other* than `colClasses` (since `as.is` sounds like such a likely candidate), while that question was about *how* to use `colClasses`.

I'll reiterate that I don't actually like this solution, even thought it's pretty simple. Quotes denote text fields in a .csv, and they don't seem to be respected in this case. The LibreOffice .csv import has a checkbox for "Treat quoted fields as text," which I'd think is analogous to `as.is = T` in R. Obviously not! #end_rant

Comment: The other solutions didn't work for me, but this one does.

Answer (score 4):

I have this issue too. Of course you can manually specify colClasses, but why is this necessary when data is quoted? I agree with the OP's 'rant' in the answer posted to his own question:

> Quotes denote text fields in a .csv, and they don't seem to be
>   respected in this case.

Anyway, I elected to use data.table's `fread()` which doesn't have this issue. Still annoying behaviour for `read.csv` though.

```
# here's a data frame with chr and int columns
my_df <- data.frame(chars=letters[1:5],
                    nums=1:5,
                    txt_nums=sprintf('%02d', 1:5),
                    stringsAsFactors=F)

# all looks as it should
lapply(my_df, class)

# $chars
# [1] "character"
# 
# $nums
# [1] "integer"
# 
# $txt_nums
# [1] "character"
```

But now, write to csv, read it back in, and the third column is coerced to int!

```
# quote=T redundant since that's the default, but just to be sure
write.csv(my_df, 'my_df.csv', row.names=F, quote=T) 
my_df2 <- read.csv('my_df.csv')
lapply(my_df2, class)

# even with as.is=TRUE, same issue
my_df2 <- read.csv('my_df.csv', as.is=T)
lapply(my_df2, class)

# data.table's fread doesn't have this issue, at least
library(data.table)
my_dt <- fread('my_df.csv')
lapply(my_dt, class)
```

Comment: Since data.table 1.11.0, fread no longer respect quoting of numeric values: "Numeric data that has been quoted is now detected and read as numeric."

Answer (score 2):

I expect there's a better method, but one option would be to use `quote=""`

```
test <- read.csv("C:/path/test.csv", as.is = TRUE, quote = "")
```

This would make the quotes part of the values, giving you:

```
test
#col1 col2  col3
#1  apple  100 "00234"
#2 banana  200 "00345"
#3 carrot  300 "00456"
```

You could then either keep them in that format, or use something like gsub to remove them:

```
test$col3 <- gsub('"', '', test$col3)

test
#col1 col2  col3
#1  apple  100 00234
#2 banana  200 00345
#3 carrot  300 00456
```

You can use some kind of apply-type function to do the gsub on the whole data frame at once:

```
test <- as.data.frame(sapply(test,gsub,pattern='"',replacement=""))
```

sapply code taken from: [R - how to replace parts of variable strings within data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487164/)

Obviously, this method will only be useful to you if you don't need the quotes elsewhere for other reasons.

Comment: I ran across something similar [on the R mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/read-csv-quotes-within-fields-td4656645.html). I forget why, now, but when I read that prior to posting this question, I had an aversion to doing this. `gsub()` wouldn't be that bad on a single column in this case. I'll post another answer after inquiring with some friends who are R users (using `colClasses`). Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The popular "readr" package also respects the quotes in .csv files.

```
test <- read_csv("C:/path/test.csv")
```

I couldn't agree more that the base R `read.csv()` behavior is unacceptable.