# In R, How to remove some unwanted charaters from the CSV file names and also extract dates?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a folder which contains some 2000 CSVs with file names that contain character '`[ ]`' in it - e.g.: `[Residential]20151001_0000_1.csv`

I want to:

- Remove '[]' from names so that we have file name as:

  **Residential_20151001_0000_1.csv**

  and place new files within a new folder.
- The read all the files from that new folder in one data frame (without header) after **skipping first row** from each file.
- Also extract **20151001** as date (e.g. 2015-10-01) in a new vector as list such that the new vector is:

  File Name  Date

  Residential_20151001_0000_1.csv  2015-10-01

Comment: Yes Akrun, because they all are related to one big issue, convert file names, store in a separate folder, read all into on data frame that should not have header and skips first line of each CSVs while reading it.

Comment: This sounds a lot like you want the SO community to do your work for you...

Comment: Well guys, do not take it otherwise... If you can't help, at least stop making comments that I am wanting others to do my job. If I could have done it myself, I would never have posted my issues here on stackoverflow. I need help, and thanks very much for your thoughts otherwise, you may well keep it with you.

Comment: You are taking some flak @ManojKumar because the questions you ask are mildly easy to google. I added an answer with how I would find the info you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will answer your first question albeit with a small change in logic. 
Firstly, lets create a backup of all the `csv` containing `[]` by copying them to another folder. For eg - If your `csv`s were in directory `"/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Sub"`, we will copy them in the folder `Backup`.

Therefore,

```
library(stringr)
library(tools)
setwd("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Sub")
dir.create("Backup")
files<-data.frame(file=list.files(path=".", pattern = "*.csv"))
for (f in files)
file.copy(from= file.path("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Sub", files$file), to= "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Sub/Backup")
```

This has now copied all the csv files to folder Backup.

Now lets rename the files in your original working directory by removing the "[]".
I have taken a slightly longer route by creating a dataframe with the old names and new names to make things easier for you.

```
Name<-file_path_sans_ext(files$file)
files<-cbind(files, Name)
files$Name<-gsub("\\[", "",files$Name)
files$Name<-gsub("\\]", "_",files$Name)
files$Name<-paste(files$Name,".csv",sep="")
```

This dataframe looks like:

```
files
     file                            Name
1 [Residential]20150928_0000_4.csv Residential_20150928_0000_4.csv
2 [Residential]20151001_0000_1.csv Residential_20151001_0000_1.csv
3 [Residential]20151101_0000_3.csv Residential_20151101_0000_3.csv
4 [Residential]20151121_0000_2.csv Residential_20151121_0000_2.csv
5 [Residential]20151231_0000_5.csv Residential_20151231_0000_5.csv
```

Now lets rename the files to remove the "[]". The idea here is to replace file with Name:

```
for ( f in files$file)
file.rename(from=file.path("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Sub", files$file), 
            to=file.path("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Sub",files$Name))
```

You've renamed your files now. If you run: `list.files(path=".", pattern = "*.csv")` You will get the new files:

```
"Residential_20150928_0000_4.csv" 
"Residential_20151001_0000_1.csv" 
"Residential_20151101_0000_3.csv"
"Residential_20151121_0000_2.csv" 
"Residential_20151231_0000_5.csv"
```

Try it!

Comment: For this code to work directly for you, just change the working directory to suit yours and execute. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks a tom MaxPD. I am on it. will revert if any issues.

Comment: I kind of changed my code a little bit in the line - `files$NewName<-str_replace_all(files$Name, "[^[:alnum:][:blank:]+_]", "")`.

Comment: Dont forget the packages.

Comment: Packages used are "stringr" and "tools". I used the following function:  files$NewName1 <- str_replace_all(gsub("[[]", "", files$file), "[]]", "_") to remove first bracket '[' and to replace second bracket ']' with an and underscore _  , which worked. Thanks for help, mate!  I got the following result, as what is desired: Residential_20151001_0000_1.csv

Comment: Check my new edit in 30 secs. Smooth code now .

Comment: please dont forget to accept as answer.

Comment: If you need help with the other Q's make another one. But only 1 or 2 Qs at a time. Do not overload SO pls.

Comment: Sure Max. Will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order:

- After googling `r replace part of string` I found: [R - how to replace parts of variable strings within data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487164/r-how-to-replace-parts-of-variable-strings-within-data-frame). This should get you up and running for this issue.
- For skipping the first line, read the documentation of `read.csv`. There you will find the `skip` argument.
- Have a look at the `strftime`/`strptime` functions. Alternatively, have a look at `lubridate`.

Comment: lubridate functions can work with data and not with file name. thanks Paul for help.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you mean here. `lubridate` contains functions that can transform the string filename to a date object..